# How to prevent mat-expansion-panel from closing?

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, accordion, accordionpane

I have matAccordion in my page in which the number of panels are dynamic. Each of these panels contain a form. I want to prevent the closing of my panel until the form is duly filled and is valid.

I am not able to find any event that will prevent the panel from closing. The "(closed)" event fires after the panel close animation has happened.

Is there some logic to control the close?

Comment: You can use `[disabled]="isDisabled"` on `mat-expansion-panel`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution there

your-component.html

```
...
<mat-expansion-panel [opened]="panelOpened($event)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header [ngClass]="(isPanelOpened)?'no-events':'default'">...</mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
...
```

your-component.ts

```
...
isPanelOpened: boolean = false;
...
panelOpened(event) {
    this.isPanelOpened = true;
}

submitForm() {
    // submit form stuff
    ...
    // at the end
    this.isPanelOpened = false;
}
...
```

your-component.css

```
.no-events {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.default {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

On first panel open it will change `isPanelOpened` to true what removes event trigger on your mat-panel. That means user can not close it unlin the form is submitted. At the end of the `submitForm()` your are switching `isPanelOpened` to false what allows user to close the panel.

Comment: But this will also block the click event right? I want to trigger a validation if user tries closing the panel without filling out form

Comment: Well I tried this approach after which I realised that doing pointer-events: none also does not allow me to fill my form. Like selecting radio buttons or dropdown values.

Comment: try to add `pointer-events: auto` on your form, that should work

Comment: btw I think adding `pointer-events: none` to your `mat-expansion-header` should not have influence to your form, but maybe someone else could express that

Comment: If you don't want to add classes to your CSS then you can simply use single style binding in your mat-expanstion-panel-header, eg. `<mat-expansion-panel-header [style.pointer-events]="isPanelOpened ? 'none' : 'auto'">`

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your CSS, which has a rule that disables pointer events:

```css
.disabled-pointer {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then add this class conditionally to your `mat-expansion-panel-header`, e.g.:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel-header [class]="formIsValid ? 'disabled-pointer' : ''">
    <mat-panel-title>Panel title</mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

To hide the toggle icon from the header, add the `hideToggle` prop conditionally to your `mat-accordion`, e.g.:

```html
<mat-accordion [hideToggle]="formIsValid ? true : false">
    ...
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="!formSubmited$ | async"></mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: Tried this one. Does not help

Answer (score 0):

You can add an click event to the element (probably mat-expansion-panel-header) and stopPropagation for that.

Here's the code:

```
<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
```